# wxPython StaticText added to sizer

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a sizer with headline :

```
    self.label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("Elements:"))
    sizer_1 = wx.FlexGridSizer(2, 5, 5, 10)
    sizer_1.Add(self.label, 0, 0, 0)
```

I have many other objects in the sizer which are added later on.
I would like the label to be the only object in the first line of the sizer.
No matter how much i played with the flags which are listed [here](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html#Add)
I couldn't find out how to set it. (I don't want to scratch the label on the whole line)

I want it to be looked like this:
(order/number of elements bellow is irreverent)

```
Elements
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9
```

at the moment what I get is:

```
Elements 1 2 3
4 5 6 etc...
```

numbers represents other objects text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a vertically oriented `BoxSizer`. Add the label and the `FlexGridSizer` to the BoxSizer. Set the box sizer as the sizer for your panel/frame/whatever instead of the `FlexGridSizer` . That should just about do it.

Nesting sizers inside of each other is a powerful and very useful thing to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about python but with C++, we can use wxStaticBoxSizer as it support the label display, same as the LabelFrame in tkinter or group/frame in some other languages.

You should layout your gui by the other BoxSizer/GridBoxSizer first and then add StaticBoxSizer inside, you will got the better look.

Ex:

```
wxStaticBoxSizer *sizer = new wxStaticBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL, panel, "Label here");
```